# Configuring s3cmd non-interactively through bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, configuration-files, s3cmd

I am trying to configure s3cmd. When at the command line,

```
s3cmd --configure
```

runs the wizard and the data entry is straight forward.
Now, I want to run this through a bash script. I used:

```
s3cmd --configure --access_key=XXXXXXX --secret_key=XXXXXX -s --no-encrypt
```

and the interactive wizard still pops out asking me the params I just supplied. I then tried dumping out the contents of the config file (.s3cfg) and writing it to a file in the root hoping s3cmd would read it:

```
s3cmd --configure --access_key=XXXXXXX --secret_key=XXXXXX -s --no-encrypt 
--dump-config 2>&1 | tee .s3cfg
```

but that didn't work either..
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--configure` is an interactive mode to define all settings so as soon as you turn this option it will bring the interactive questions mode.

If you want to script the configuration of the tool, I think you should directly edit the `.s3cfg` (for mac/linux) or `s3cmd.ini` (for windows) in your user home directory and set the values you want to set.

Alternatively you can dump the current settings (as you made with `--dump-config`) make change and save using `s3cmd --config=<new_file>`

Comment: I went ahead and dumped the config file into a .s3cfg file within /root/. S3cmd was able to read it directly without having to explicitly point towards it.    `s3cmd --configure --access_key=XXXXXX --secret_key=XXXX -s --no-encrypt --dump-config 2>&1 | tee /root/.s3cfg`

Answer (score 1):

Simply removing the --configure option will do the trick. The authors command was allmost correct

```
s3cmd --access_key=XXXXXXX --secret_key=XXXXXX -s --no-encrypt 
--dump-config 2>&1 | tee .s3cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

At least with version *1.1.0-beta3*, this worked well for me:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...

echo -e "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID?}\n${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY?}\n\n\n\n\nY\ny\n" | \
  s3cmd --configure
```

I'd recommend doing it once manually to figure out the exact succession of input strings required, and then adapting the echo command accordingly (you have the 
option not to save the config file in the interactive mode).

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: No need to export the variables when they're used that way. Anyway, I would read them from a file instead in order to avoid exposing them on the command line: `s3cmd --configure < s3values.txt`